# clearInterval not stopping interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape some links with headless-chrome/puppeteer while scrolling down like this:

```
 let interval
 const linkScraper = async () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
               interval = setInterval(async () => {
                const visiblePosts = await page.$$("div[class*='wrapper']")
                const data = await handleVisiblePosts(visiblePosts)
                allPosts = {...allPosts, ...data}
                await scroll()
                const stop = await areWeAtTheBottom()
                if (stop) {              
                    console.log('STOPPING')              
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    resolve()                
                }
            }, 100); 

           })
          }
```

problem? clearInterval doesn't actually stop the interval. `stopping` gets printed multiple times.

I suspect it could also be because setinterval is async, which it needs to be in order to use `await`.

Comment: How many times do you call `linkScraper` and are you expecting one `clearInterval` to stop **all** running instances of `linkScraper`?

Comment: `linkScraper` is called just once

Comment: I highly doubt it gets called only once. Let's examine that statement. Somehow you found some long standing bug in a highly and widely used language like javascript and everyone else on the planet using `setInterval` doesn't seem to have a problem stopping them except you `clearInterval` doesn't work. Hmm.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can find the following possible reasons why your interval would not get stopped:

1. You are never getting to the `stop` condition.
2. You are overwriting the `interval` variable somehow so the actual interval you want to stop is no longer saved.
3. You are getting a rejected promise.

There does not appear to be any reason why the `interval` variable needs to be outside the `linkScraper` function and putting it inside the function will prevent it from getting overwritten in any way.

With this many `await` calls, it seems wise to add a try/catch to catch any rejected promises and stop the interval if there's an error.

If you see the `STOPPING` being logged, then you are apparently hitting the stop condition so it appears it would have to be an overwritten `interval` variable.

Here's a version that cannot overwrite the `interval` variable and makes a few other changes for code cleanliness:

```
 const linkScraper = async () => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const interval = setInterval(async () => {
             try {
                 const visiblePosts = await page.$$("div[class*='wrapper']");
                 const data = await handleVisiblePosts(visiblePosts);
                 allPosts = { ...allPosts, ...data};
                 await scroll();
                 const stop = await areWeAtTheBottom();
                 if (stop) {
                     console.log('STOPPING');
                     clearInterval(interval);
                     resolve();
                 }
             } catch(e) {
                 clearInterval(interval);
                 reject(e);
             }
         }, 100);

     });
 }
```

---

In cleaning up this code, I ran into a couple questions:

1. Do all four of your functions that you use `await` with actually return a promise?
2. And, where is `allPosts` declared?

---

**EDIT:** Just discovered another issue.  `setInterval()` isn't aware of the `await` calls inside your function.  Remember, the outer function doesn't actually block.  It returns immediately as soon as you hit an `await`.  That means that you can get another `setInterval()` callback while you were still processing the async operations of the first one.  That will mess things up.  Here's a way around that:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

const linkScraper = () => {
        console.log("starting linkScraper");

        async function run() {
            const visiblePosts = await page.$$("div[class*='wrapper']");
            const data = await handleVisiblePosts(visiblePosts);
            allPosts = { ...allPosts, ...data};
            await scroll();
            const stop = await areWeAtTheBottom();
            if (stop) {
                console.log('STOPPING');
                return "stop";
            }
            return "continue";
        }

        return run().then(result => {
            if (result === "continue") {
                return delay(100).then(run);
            }
        })

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting `STOPPING` printed multiple times. I also made sure that linkScraper/Promise is indeed getting invoked just once `console.log('Promise called')` just below `new Promise...` line. 

2: allPosts is declared just outside the linkScraper `let allPosts = {}`

Comment: @NemaGa - I see another problem.  `setInterval()` doesn't wait for your `await` operations.  So, while you're doing one `await` inside a `setInterval()` callback, the next interval can get called and so on.  Am working on a way to fix that.

Comment: @NemaGa - I added a new part to the end of my answer that shows a different approach that works around the `setInterval()` issue by using a repeated `setTimeout()` that we can control to not fire until each run of the loop is done (which we couldn't control with `setInterval()`).

Answer (score 0):

I accepted jfriend00's solution as it pointed me in the right direction, my slightly modified, final and working version looks like this:

```
const linkScraper = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const run = async () => {
            console.log("running")
            const visiblePosts = await page.$$("div[class*='wrapper']");
            const data = await handleVisiblePosts(visiblePosts);
            allPosts = {...allPosts, ...data};
            await scroll();
            const stop = await areWeAtTheBottom();
            if (stop) {
                console.log('STOPPING');
                resolve()
            } else {
                await page.waitFor(100)
                await run()
            }

        }

        await run()         
    })
}
```